Transcendental eigen equations with Bessel functions
Excuse me if I ask again the same question.
I've seen that in my previous question the presence of a derivative was confusing, so I ask it again a way that I hope more clear.
I need to find a solution for f[x] of this equation
I BesselJ[0, f[x]]/(f[x] BesselJ[1, f[x]]) == g[x]

where g[x] is a given function.
Thanks a lot for the help and for the patience
